# Have Job Interview on Thursday how do I get time off for it without revealing its a job interview?

Tags: interviewing, united-kingdom

Currently in a job right now but I've been looking for something that suits my skillset more and I've been invited for a job interview.

Problem is how I go about telling my boss about it. Because on one hand I don't want to take more time off but on the other hand if I tell them they'll likely find a reason to sack me.

So I'm wondering about how I can get the time off without letting my boss know I'm going to a job interview?

Comment: Take a day-off for personal reasons

Answer (score -1):

wtf ? Just book time off, no need to tell them anything.

or if its nearby just do it at lunch, while you are meeting a friend.